# Is retrofit fast?

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

I am now using a retrofit.

In addition, I use the following libraries.

=================

gson-2.8.2.jar

gson-2.8.2-javadoc.jar

hamcrest-core-1.3.jar

junit-4.12.jar

okhttp-3.9.1.jar

okio-1.13.0.jar

retrofit-2.3.0.jar

================

Q: Can retro fits be really fast?

As a result of my testing, it is too slow.

Retrofit Average speed: 2500 ms, personal code average speed: 900ms

Is it true that I used it properly? (Kotlin)

Below is a code that uses Retrofit.

```
interface ApiService {
@GET("/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/{name}")
fun getSummonerByName(@Path("name") name : String, @Query("api_key") apiKey : String): Call<SummonerDTO>
}



fun getSummonerByName(summonerName: String, apiKey: String): SummonerDTO? {
    var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://" + HOST + "").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
    var service = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    var repos = service.getSummonerByName(summonerName, apiKey)
    val response = repos.execute()
    if(response.isSuccessful){
        return response.body()
    }
    return null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an advisory answer to this stupid question.

The speed of the Retrofit is usually done in the background and called as a callback function.
So the test method is wrong. Use HttpsURLConnection if you only want one quick connection without considering any software architecture or pattern. It is concise and short. However, if you want asynchronous processing, use Retrofit. Easy and powerful.